# Select a location on the map depending on which button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like below. By default the location is `myloc`. When user clicks `btn-a` it selects `myloc` and when `btn-b` is clicked it select `myloc1`. In my code I repeat the code `L.circle` three times, which is bad practice. So can anybody help me? How can I optimize this code, DRY it up and improve the quality as well?

```
var myloc = new L.LatLng(13.7433242, 100.5421583);
var myloc1 = new L.LatLng(14.979900, 102.097771);
$(function () {
    var circle;
    var slider = document.getElementById('myRange');
    var output = document.getElementById('demo');
    output.innerHTML = slider.value + scale;

    slider.oninput = function (val) {
        output.innerHTML = this.value + scale;
        circle.setRadius(this.value);
    }

    circle = L.circle(myloc, {
        color: '#7a7777',
        weight: 0.1,
        fillColor: '#7a7777',
        fillOpacity: 0.2,
        radius: 0
    }).addTo(map);

    $('.btn-a').on('click', function(e){
        if ($(this).val() == 'First') {
            circle = L.circle(myloc, {
                color: '#7a7777',
                weight: 0.1,
                fillColor: '#7a7777',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                radius: 0
            }).addTo(map);

        } else if($(this).val() == 'Second') {
            circle = L.circle(myloc1, {
                color: '#7a7777',
                weight: 0.1,
                fillColor: '#7a7777',
                fillOpacity: 0.2,
                radius: 0
            }).addTo(map);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know who proposed the edit, but I rejected it since it didn't solve the issue. The current title is more along the lines of what we're looking for. If it's inaccurate in any way, please feel free to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

To DRY up your code, you need to use a variable to call the same code with different input.s It seems like if you had something like this:

```
const circles = {
   First: myloc,
   Second: myloc1
}
```

Then you'd be able to dry up the `click` code:

```
L.circle(circles[$(this).val()], {
            color: '#7a7777',
            weight: 0.1,
            fillColor: '#7a7777',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            radius: 0
        }).addTo(map)
```